# splitting a list in a better way using list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have a simple list that I am splitting and concatenating. My code uses for loop and if condition and ugly. Can you suggest a better way using list comprehension?

**My code**

```
mylist = ['10.10.10.1','10.10.10.2,10.10.10.3,10.10.10.4,10.10.10.5','10.10.10.6']

mylist = [i.split(",") for i in mylist] 
list =[]
for x,y in enumerate(mylist):
    if len(y) == 1:
        list.append(y[0])
    else:
        for z in y:
            list.append(z)
print(list)
```

I am getting the below result and exactly the way i want
    ['10.10.10.1','10.10.10.2','10.10.10.3','10.10.10.4','10.10.10.5','10.10.10.6']

Comment: This question is probably better served to be asked here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga. However hope we can avoid that second looping since he is checking for empty values returning while splitting

```
In [7]: s=['10.10.10.1','','10.10.10.2,10.10.10.3,10.10.10.4,10.10.10.5','10.10.10.6']

In [8]: [splitRec for rec in s for splitRec in rec.split(',') if splitRec]
Out[8]: 
['10.10.10.1',
 '10.10.10.2',
 '10.10.10.3',
 '10.10.10.4',
 '10.10.10.5',
 '10.10.10.6']

In [9]: s=['10.10.10.1',',,','10.10.10.2,10.10.10.3,10.10.10.4,10.10.10.5','10.10.10.6']

In [10]: [splitRec for rec in s for splitRec in rec.split(',') if splitRec]Out[10]: 
['10.10.10.1',
 '10.10.10.2',
 '10.10.10.3',
 '10.10.10.4',
 '10.10.10.5',
 '10.10.10.6']
```

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
[s for string in mylist for s in string.split(',')]
```

Note, your original approach wouldn't be so bad if you just simplified. No need for `enumerate` and no need to check the length, so just:

```
final_list =[]
for sub in mylist:
    for s in sub:
         final_list.append(s)
```

By the way, you shouldn't shadow the built-in `list`. Use another name

Answer (score 1):

Not a comprehension, but good anyway, I think.

```
','.join(mylist).split(',')
```

Comment: Yeah I agree however the empty values of list also needs a loop or a logic to be filtered out. That's when I thought of using a list comp also since we are looking out for a list type as return. Just a thought.

Comment: @Varad I don't see any empty values in their list.

Comment: Yeah, its not there in his given list. However he is adding a logic in his program where is enumerates and tries to find the length of list to see if its empty. That made me think he is looking to filter out the empty ones.

Comment: @Varad that isn't what the conditional logic checks in OPs implementation, indeed, it is completely equivalent to what I have in my answer,  and it doesn't filter out empty values

Comment: @Varad Huh? There's only one length check, and it's for length 1 (and completely unnecessary).

Comment: Oops my bad. Its on @Ramesh Rajan's code. Not here.. where he checks if length is 1 and then does an append. Else he loops. I'm sorry I did over see that filtering out of empty string, Excuse me. Its my bad.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Just a thought or a question does it make sense to handle for empty values to be safe just to be on a safer fail proof side.

Comment: @Varad I'd say no.

Answer (score 0):

You can first just split each string on `','`:

```
>>> mylist = ['10.10.10.1','10.10.10.2,10.10.10.3,10.10.10.4,10.10.10.5','10.10.10.6']
>>> split_str = [x.split(',') for x in mylist]
>>> split_str
[['10.10.10.1'], ['10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3', '10.10.10.4', '10.10.10.5'], ['10.10.10.6']]
```

Then if you want to flatten it, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(split_str))
['10.10.10.1', '10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3', '10.10.10.4', '10.10.10.5', '10.10.10.6']
```